# An (erosive/eroding) job/task/action etc

Tags: word-request

I wonder what adjective do you normally use to describe an action / a task which as time passes causes you to wear out and makes you exhausted. These kinds of jobs are not at all boring at first, but by the lapse of time make you tired and maybe fed up with continuing them. These actions/jobs/tasks etc. are somewhat eroding your patience body after by the passage of time. So, after a period of time you might not be interested to them (at all).

**For instance:**

> — Even if you have a team, lexicography is a/an.................job. It requires lots of patience and love. Otherwise, it can make you exhausted after a short while.

I don't know any word in English encompassing this concept, but I think using "erossive/eroding" in a figurative sense (of course if it works,) would be my needed adjective.

Comment: Idiomatically, the "standard" term here is probably *lexicography is a **demanding** job*, but there are plenty of "more-or-less" synonymous alternatives - *difficult, challenging, taxing, tough, hard, onerous, burdensome, stressful, arduous, tiring, exhausting, back-breaking,...*

Comment: ...I think the word with the *exact* sense you're looking for might be *a **corrosive** job*, but that's not idiomatically natural in English. You could maybe get away with that if you use it with supporting context: *It's a corrosive job. When you've worked at it for years, it eats away your self-respect and your faith in the future*. But that's very much "creative writing", not really natural English.

Comment: Is it understood by a great majority of native speakrs from all around the world @FumbleFingers or it is just sort of a made-up word?

Comment: Why would you not have gone with the word you use in the description of what you're looking for? ***Exhausting***.

Comment: Because the word I need (would be better figuratively) have some connections with "erosion" Jason! Meanwhile, something that is "exhausting" just makes you overly tired! That's all! But the word in my question is more about making you fed up with something as time passes; (something that you could be keen on at the begining) the part that "exhausting" is missing it!

Comment: If you @FumbleFingers were supposed to chose a word among "laborious", "taxing", demanding", "arduous" and "Grueling", "wearing" and "overwhelming" I wonder what would be your first two choices for this meaning?

Comment: If I was really keen to convey your *specific* nuance, I might choose something like ***debilitating*** or ***draining***. But this is really just "writing advice", and you just might want to be "creative" and use ***corrosive*** anyway (the fact that this would be an uncommon usage simply forces your audience to pay attention, ***if*** they assume you used that word consciously and deliberately). But ***grueling*** is pretty evocative too.